# lp print-quality not working

Tags: macos, cups, lp

Running following command works, but printer always prints really fast.

```bash
cat /Users/sunknudsen/Downloads/7663f4bd.pdf | lp -o media=4x6 -o print-quality=5
```

Printing same file using macOS print dialog and selecting “Best” quality results in slowing (and better) printing.

Is `print-quality=5` equivalent to “Best”?

Comment: Not very familiar with the print dialog on macos but does it also use cups?  If not it's probably a driver issue.  I guess either way it's likely a driver issue.  If you are using cups you have driver issues.

Comment: Thanks for helping out @jesse_b. macOS does use CUPS under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Found fix…

```bash
cat /Users/sunknudsen/Downloads/7663f4bd.pdf | lp -o MediaType=stationery-heavyweight -o PageSize=Custom.4x6in -o Quality=High
```

`MediaType=stationery-heavyweight` is what slows things down.